# Django: can't bind an uploaded image to a form ImageField()

Tags: python, django, forms, binding, upload

here's my problem, I've created this form:

```
class SettingsForm(forms.Form):  
    ...  
    logo = forms.ImageField()  
    ...
```

The upload works fine and I managed to display the image but I can't bind it to the form. Here's what I've done:

```
data = ...  
files = {'logo': SimpleUploadedFile('logo.jpg', logo.read())}  
form = SettingsForm(data=data, files=files)
```

the logo object is a `ImageFieldFile`. I've tested the read method in a shell, it's ok. I've got no warnings displaying the page, only "no file chosen".

Thanks for your help. Sorry for the format of this post, I'm new to stackoverflow and to django.

Comment: SimpleUploadedFile 3rd parameter content_type defaults to 'text/plain', could it be the problem?

Comment: Still not working with 'image/jpeg'

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about this, but according to the django documentation, on binding forms, the data and files are not kwargs, but are args, so try this:

```
form = SettingsForm(data, files)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this code is working:
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SettingsForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES,...)

I'm using kwargs because I'm calling Super() in my form code. You can't see it because I haven't pasted the full code of my form, should I?

Thx for your help